# Facebook video auto play

Tags: facebook, video

Can I autoplay embed facebook video?
Tried adding `<param name=\"autoplay\" value=\"true\" />`
but it's not do not helped.

```
<object width=\"{0}\" height=\"{1}\" >
<param name=\"allowfullscreen\" value=\"true\" />
<param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.facebook.com/v/{2}\" />
<param name=\"autoplay\" value=\"true\" />
<embed src=\"http://www.facebook.com/v/{2}\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"{0}\" height=\"{1}\"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after the src of the video... 
       &autoplay=1